# JavaScript animation position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basketball and a basketball button. When I click the button, the basketball bounces up and down. I've managed to style the basketball and button to my desired location on the screen.

But when I click on the "Animate Basketball" button the ball does bounce up and down, but it relocates itself to the top of my page and then starts bouncing up and down. Can someone please look at my code and tell how I can stop the ball from relocating when I click the button?

```
<head>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<input id="ballButton" onclick="checkButton()" type="button" value="Animate Basketball"
<div id="basketball" style="position:absolute;top:430px;left:700px;">
   <img src="http://img.netlumination.com/Basketball_64x64-1.png" Basketball" \>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ballButton {
  position:absolute;
  top:400px;
  left:700px
}
```

JS:

```
var distanceBall = 0;
var directionBall = 1;
var timerToggle = null;
function animateBall() {
  document.getElementById("basketball").style.top = distanceBall + "px";
  distanceBall += directionBall;
  if (distanceBall > 200) { directionBall = -1; }
  if (0 > distanceBall) { directionBall = 1; }
  timerToggle = setTimeout(function () { animateBall(); }, 10);
}

function checkButton() {
  if (document.getElementById("ballButton").value == "Animate Basketball") {
    document.getElementById("ballButton").value = "Stop Basketball";
    animateBall();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ballButton").value = "Animate Basketball";
    clearTimeout(timerToggle);
  }
}
```

Comment: A jsfiddle or code snippet would be wonderful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (though quick and dirty) **working** solution. I think this is what you meant.

http://jsfiddle.net/9guaa0j5/1/

I added some pixels to your starting variable `distanceBall` and manually added 230px to one of your functions.

```
var distanceBall = 200;
var directionBall = 1;
var timerToggle = null;
function animateBall() {
document.getElementById("basketball").style.top = distanceBall + 230 +"px";
distanceBall += directionBall;
if (distanceBall > 200) { directionBall = -1; }
if (0 > distanceBall) { directionBall = 1; }
timerToggle = setTimeout(function () { animateBall(); }, 10);
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks a lot man, distanceBall was the issue and i know this for my future coding endeavors!

Comment: I'm glad i could help!

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `distanceBall` is the problem. When you fetch the basketball with `getElementById` your code says that its CSS 'top' property is 0px. Change the `distanceBall` variable to about 410px. 
here is an example: [Working ball animation](https://www.codecademy.com/FlipFloopPower/codebits/foy94q)

here is another codebit that can help: [CSS ball animation](https://www.codecademy.com/FlipFloopPower/codebits/XS7Cr1)

Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks a lot man this did help a lot, although the distanceBall was solved by the Fausta NA first, however i will be using your CSS ball animation on another part of my site, I'm a huge NBA fan!